# Magento Custom Error Page

Tags: magento-1.9, error

I am wondering how I would go about giving all errors in Magento other than 404 errors a custom errror page that says something along the lines of "Something went wrong". I want all of them to pull up the same error page. How would I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In folder /var/www/html/errors copy folder called default and name it {your name}, then in local.xml in /var/www/html/errors place this code

```
<config>
   <skin>{your name}</skin>
</config>
```

Then go to /var/www/html/errors/{your name} and modify your error pages as you see fit including css and images. Don't forget to set the correct variables in processor.php

For more detailed information follow [this](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/customizing-the-magento-error-report-and-maintenance-page/) link.

Answer (score 1):

You can select design of error page in {root_dir}/erros folder. In design.xml change code:

```
<config>
    <skin>{your_skin_name}</skin>
</config>
```

And in this folder create new folder `{your_skin_name}` and copy files from `/errors/default` to this folder and than you can edit them.